# Write all outerText to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write out all outerText values to an array.

This is based on a class selector

jQuery is usable my attempt is below syntax invalid e.g.

```
array =[];
  $( ".v-captiontext" ).each(function( index )
{
  array.push($( this ).outerText() )    
    );
});
```

Comment: note: outerText is not a standard

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [];

$(".v-captiontext").each(function(index) {
  array.push($(this).outerText());   
});
```

is the correct syntax. Seems like you are not using any IDE. Start using one.

Comment: While the syntax is correct, the code will still not work. jQuery has no `outerText()` method.

Comment: `.outerText()` needs to be `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the reason you have invalid syntax is because you have an extra `)` in the code. If you format your code it makes it easier to spot mistakes like this.

With regard to your goal, `outerText` is the property of an Element object, not a jQuery object or a method. Call it on the `this` reference directly:

```
let array = [];
$(".v-captiontext").each(function() {
  array.push(this.outerText);
});
```

Also note that you can simplify this further by using `map()` instead of `each()`:

```
let array = $(".v-captiontext").map((i, el) => el.outerText).get();
```

Comment: Did you mean `el.outerText` and not `el.outerText()`?

Comment: @Keith yes indeed! Thank you

Comment: @epascarello agreed, however the OP always refers to 'outerText' so I'm assuming it's not  a mistake on their part.